# does gwt panel clear method un attach event handlers?

Tags: gwt

in gwt Panel.clear() method clears all child widgets.  Does that mean all even handlers associated with those child widgets will be removed or garbage collected as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will (at least if the child widget cleaned their reference to application-transversal objects like the eventBus and don't hold circular references).

As per [this documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UnderstandingMemoryLeaks)

> The core GWT widget
> system has a very specific event-handling system that makes it
> impossible to trigger a leak.
> It will also work in IE, as long as you
> don't go straight to JSNI and hook up event handlers yourself (using
> things like Event.sinkEvents() is just fine).
>
> Calling Widget.removeEventListener() or
> HandlerRegistration.removeHandler() **is never necessary (or useful)
> for any reason other than that you want to stop
> receiving events** (this is one reason we tucked removeHandler() into
> HandlerRegistration -- most people never need to call it).

and [this blog post](http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2010/11/23/gwt-handlers.html).

> However, removeHandler is required to avoid application-level, java-esque memory
> leaks.
>
> If you have a “global” event source, like an always-visible navigation
> bar widget or an application-wide EventBus, and you have a transient
> event listener, like a presenter listening for events, the presenter’s
> event handler will keep it from being garbage collected until the
> EventBus is also garbage collected.

So don't worry about widgets or @UIHandler. Just clear the tab and it'll work.

Comment: Yet, it seems GWT still leaks a lot (check the comments in the links above).

Answer (score -1):

No it will not. You have to call [removeHandler()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/HandlerRegistration.html#removeHandler%28%29). (eventually)

In [this doumcnetation](http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2010/11/23/gwt-handlers.html):

>

> 2 .  removeHandler is required to avoid application-level memory leaks.
>
> If you have a “global” event source, like an always-visible navigation
>   bar widget or an application-wide EventBus, and you have a transient
>   event listener, like a presenter listening for events, the presenter’s
>   event handler will keep it from being garbage collected until the
>   EventBus is also garbage collected.